# Overriding PHP settings in PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I am on Debian 7 Wheezy, with Apache2 Worker and PHP-FPM running with FastCGI. I have multiple websites (and pools) running on it, some of them managed by their own webmasters with no access to the global php configuration or pools configurations.

I'm looking for a way to override PHP ini settings on a per-directory basis.
From what I gathered from other questions here and various pages on the internet, it seems that it is not possible to use .htaccess as I did under mod_php5; nor I can use .user.ini files because apparently they only work with the CGI/FastCGI SAPI.

so....what's left? no way to override setting with FPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think that after some testing I have found the answer.

.user.ini files **do actually work** in php-fpm. The only problem that I found is that apparently you cannot override settings that have been set in the pool configuration files.